# Invalid ARN specified for bucket name. Only access point ARNs are allowed for the value of bucket name

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and was trying to upload files to s3 bucket by using the following code. But I was not able to upload it.
This is the code that I've tried.

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class UploadObjectTest
    {
        private const string bucketName = "arn:aws:s3:::abc-files3";
        // For simplicity the example creates two objects from the same file.
        // You specify key names for these objects.
        private const string keyName1 = "*** key name for first object created ***";
        private const string keyName2 = "*** key name for second object created ***";
        private const string filePath = @"*** file path ***";
        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1; 

        private static IAmazonS3 client;

        public static void Main()
        {
            client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKeyId: awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey: objectKey, region: bucketRegion);
            WritingAnObjectAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task WritingAnObjectAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName1,
                    ContentBody = "sample text"
                };

                PutObjectResponse response1 = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest1);

                // 2. Put the object-set ContentType and add metadata.
                var putRequest2 = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName2,
                    FilePath = filePath,
                    ContentType = "text/plain"
                };
                
                putRequest2.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
                PutObjectResponse response2 = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest2);
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                        "Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object"
                        , e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object"
                    , e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, I got an error like this

> Invalid ARN specified for bucket name. Only access point ARNs are
> allowed for the value of bucket name.

can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Well, the problem is obviously on the bucket name. While it's correct that you want to hide it, with such a string it's impossible for us to know what you're actually trying to use. Try to edit and use a fake yet "close-enough" string

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the bucketname is like arn:aws:s3:::abc-files3

Comment: So that's the problem. It's supposed to be a bucket *name*, not a bucket ARN

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ok let me check that way. Thanks a lot :)